# How could I make a Character use a device such as a magic sword after a teleport or dash?

Tags: character-creation, mutants-and-masterminds

First and foremost if you didn't get it from the question this is talking about Mutants and Masterminds. and its a question about character building. Im not sure how to tell but I think its second edition. all I know its it isnt the one that splits Dex into three separate stats

I would like to know the appropriate Powers to make a character both Dash a set distance and attack with his magic sword which is a 3 point device As a regular equipment point sword doesnt have powers. or teleport and Use the magic sword.

the character also needs to be able to use the magic sword for normal non-teleport attacks and the Dash or teleport needs to be expandable to allow for the addition of other powers later such as a Explosion or trip

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming 2nd edition) Simply use the two powers one after the other using a Move action and a Standard action. Dash, strike. Simple as that.

Your Dashing power should be either Speed 2 (if you only want to dash on walkable distance) or Teleport 2 (with flaws to limit destination to perception) if you want to be able to dash an enemy even if he's flying or above the ground.

Your attack power will be strike on your device. If you have any strength, take only 1 rank and add the power feat Mighty (so it adds your strength to the Damage bonus).

Answer (score 1):

Canonically, there is no power that lets you move and attack as a single action. You can have a form of Teleport that lets you move there, then attack, and `Move-By Action` is generally considered to work in terms of letting you move in any way, attack, then move somewhere else. The 2E *Mecha and Manga* book built that as a 3 pp Power named **Flash Step** that was a Move-Action Teleport for 100 feet of distance coupled with `Move-By Action` so that you'd basically step to behind your opponent, strike, then be away again. You could add a Power Loss Drawback of 1 PP or so for only being able to use it with a sword. Any way about it, it will cost two actions.

3E/DCA is much the same in terms of what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

While [Sean's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/how-could-i-make-a-character-use-a-device-such-as-a-magic-sword-after-a-teleport/38265#38265) and [user4000's answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/how-could-i-make-a-character-use-a-device-such-as-a-magic-sword-after-a-teleport/16941#16941) are solid I'd like to add another option to this effect, specifically for 3e (since the version isn't specified), but possibly valid for other versions.

A Ranged Attack is literally an attack at range. Since you have to aim the teleport and the attack, you could stat this effect as follows:

> Teleport Strike: Ranged Strength Damage, Feedback (1 point, Alternate Effect to Strength Damage)

Effectively, this allows you to use your Strength-based effects (such as a sword) at range, with a Ranged Attack check, but the flaw that if someone holds an action to attack you when you show up, because that's the descriptor of this effect, they can deal damage to you.

A more expensive version of this effect would be a Perception Ranged variant of you teleporting such that your sword teleports inside of someone, but that doesn't sound like what you're going for.